# Upload with curl from file_get_contents / imagecreatefromstring

Tags: php, stream

I have the follow code:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://externaldomain.com/image.png'));
```

And want to make a curl request:

```
$files = array();
$files[] = '@' . $image['tmp_name'] . ';filename=' . $image['name'] . ';type=' . $image['type'];

$ch = curl_init('index.php?route=upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $files);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The main problem is, how to get the file name and extension from `$image` variable?

I can replace `$image['tmp_name']` with `tempnam()`, but other things?

Have another way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagecreatefromstring returns a GD handle. There is no tmp_name, name, **OR** type associated with it. You're trying to treat that GD handle as if it was the result of a standard POST-based $_FILES data structure.

a GD handle cannot be passed to curl for upload, because it's not really an image, and won't be until you use imagejpeg/imagepng/imagewhatever to save it out to a file, which you can then point curl at, e.g.

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(...);
imagejpeg($image, 'tempfile.jpg');

$files[] = '@tempfile.jpg;filename=tempfile.jpg;type=image/jpeg';

curl...
```